# Zebra RFID SDK: Neither Inventory nor getReadTags/getReadTagEx API reads tag data (e.g. memorybank, opcodes are null)

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, rfid, zebra-scanners

I am attempting to use the [Zebra RFID SDK](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/software/developer-tools/rfid-sdk-for-android.html) version 2.0.2.124 to read RFID tags with a [MC3300xR](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/rfid/rfid-handhelds/mc3300xr.html#pageandfilelist_4749) handheld reader, running the [R18](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/software/firmware/mc3300r-firmware.html) firmware, and am encountering problems that I am unable to resolve and other unexpected behavior.

I am under the impression that an [inventory operation](https://techdocs.zebra.com/dcs/rfid/android/2-0-2-124/apis/com/zebra/rfid/api3/inventory) (`reader.Actions.Inventory.perform()`) should be able to access a seen tag's memory bank, and return it as a part of a [`TagData`](https://techdocs.zebra.com/dcs/rfid/android/2-0-2-124/apis/com/zebra/rfid/api3/tagdata) object (after a call to [`getReadTagsEx`](https://techdocs.zebra.com/dcs/rfid/android/2-0-2-124/apis/com/zebra/rfid/api3/actions#getReadTagsEx(int))).

However, when I review any `TagData` object returned by a `getReadTagsEx` call after performing an inventory, its `opCode`, `opStatus`, and `memoryBankData` values are *always* `null`, *no matter what* configuration settings I write to the reader.

I would expect that `opStatus` would return something like `ACCESS_OPERATION_STATUS.ACCESS_SUCCESS`, indicating a successful tag access, etc. So far, I have only been able to achieve such successful tag access operations through the [`TagAccess`](https://techdocs.zebra.com/dcs/rfid/android/2-0-2-124/apis/com/zebra/rfid/api3/tagaccess) action, but *not* through an inventory.

Again, this is *no matter how I have the reader configured*. Other answers have suggested

- Disabling dynamic power optimization (`reader.Config.setDPOState(DYNAMIC_POWER_OPTIMIZATION.DISABLE)`),
- Not attaching tag data with a read event (`reader.Events.setAttachTagDataWithReadEvent(false)`)
- Stopping an inventory before reading tags (`reader.Actions.Inventory.stop()`)

All of which I have tried, to no avail. I have also tried

- Experimenting with [`TagStorageSettings`](https://techdocs.zebra.com/dcs/rfid/android/2-0-2-124/apis/com/zebra/rfid/api3/tagstoragesettings), e.g. setting tags to report all fields (`tagStorageSettings.tagFields = arrayOf(TAG_FIELD.ALL_TAG_FIELDS)`) and enable access reports (`tagStorageSettings.enableAccessReports(true)`)
- Setting attributes directly, e.g.

```cs
val attrCtrl = SetAttribute()
attrCtrl.attnum = 1610; // ATT_RFID_ACCESS_S1_ENABLE
attrCtrl.atttype = "B";
attrCtrl.attvalue = "1";
```

- Experimenting with singulation, which is not something I understand very well.
- Experimenting with filters, with some success (at least in getting an inventory to only read tags starting with a certain prefix, for example).

also without any success.

At this point, I'm pretty convinced that either my reader or the API/SDK does not support tag access/reading memory banks during an inventory event, but I thought I would ask here, for some more opinions.

Thanks, please let me know if there is anything I can clarify.